# Word 2007 heading numbering incorrect

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a large-ish document (1.5MB, 105 pages) with headings provided by formatting styles.  Everything was fine until some point in a recent edit and now the first H1 heading is 4 (the second 5 and so on).

I've right clicked and selected Set Numbering Value at set it to 1, but it refuses to budge.

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the H1 style definition.

Base the H1 on (no style) instead of Normal.

Then the Set Number Value function will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should link your heading levels with list levels.
Do it via: Paragraph - Multilevel list - define new Multilevel list. Press "More"...

You can find out more here: [Word and numbering 2 – outline numbering](http://beancountersguide.co.uk/2007/08/08/word-and-numbering-2-outline-numbering/)